# Solving Redis warnings on overcommit_memory and Transparent Huge Pages for Ubuntu 16.04 on EC2

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, redis, sysctl, huge-pages

On a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 EC2 instance the warnings appear like so:

```
WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.
```

How to eliminate them permanently?

Comment: Somehow nobody ventured to question bullshitness of the original premises. `vm.overcommit_memory = 0` is a heuristic default (it does overcommit too) and I'd rather rely on kernel devs as opposed to clunky redis team.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Like the warning suggests, just add the line `vm.overcommit_memory=1` to the bottom of `/etc/sysctl.conf`, with something like `sudo vi /etc/sysctl.conf`.

But permissions don't allow you to edit THP as the warning suggests, so instead do

```
sudo apt install hugepages
```

and add the command `sudo hugeadm --thp-never` to the bottom of your .bashrc, with something like `sudo vi ~/.bashrc`.

Then just `sudo reboot` and next time you SSH in run `redis-server` and the warnings are gone!

Comment: Is simply making the warning go away dangerous at all? When would it be desirable for a 'background save' to fail under low memory conditions? Could it be problematic to just blindly set 'vm.overcommit_memory=1'?

Comment: @ScottSkiles: I believe Redis does a background save by calling `fork()` which immediately **doubles** the apparent memory use. But since it is all virtual memory until things change in the parent, things should be OK until the save finishes.

Comment: how to do that in docker container?

Comment: @HerilMuratovic according to discussions I've seen on github, these settings (probably) go on the host system and docker gets them from there. E.g.: https://github.com/docker-library/redis/issues/19#issuecomment-96080885

Answer (score 3):

With Linux and Ubuntu, I did this before running `redis-server`, and it seems to work...

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:redislabs/redis
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install redis
```

https://redis.io/download

Comment: Nice, it appears to be a better fix (achieved with the native library). If someone can verify that this solves the problem, then I'll award this as the new best answer.

Comment: In my case, upgrading redis to v.6.2.6 via the indicated PPA removed the Transparent Huge Page warning, but NOT the overcommit_memory one