# Docker - Redis gives a security attack error

Tags: docker, redis

I am trying to pull a redis image and start it on my windows laptop using the below commands:

```
docker pull redis
docker run -d -p 6379:6379 --name my-redis redis
```

I am running into this error:

```
C:\Users\Pavan Dittakavi>docker logs 9a0edf8bf13349c50d41996e54174dd4c5f671d321c4b0b7b2480dc052e95e60
1:C 04 Jun 2022 08:02:22.134 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
1:C 04 Jun 2022 08:02:22.134 # Redis version=7.0.0, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
1:C 04 Jun 2022 08:02:22.134 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
1:M 04 Jun 2022 08:02:22.134 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
1:M 04 Jun 2022 08:02:22.135 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
1:M 04 Jun 2022 08:02:22.135 # Server initialized
1:M 04 Jun 2022 08:02:22.135 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
1:M 04 Jun 2022 08:02:22.135 * The AOF directory appendonlydir doesn't exist
1:M 04 Jun 2022 08:02:22.135 * Ready to accept connections
1:M 04 Jun 2022 08:03:22.387 # Possible SECURITY ATTACK detected. It looks like somebody is sending POST or Host: commands to Redis. This is likely due to an attacker attempting to use Cross Protocol Scripting to compromise your Redis instance. Connection aborted.
```

Is there something that I am missing. My intention is to connect to Redis from my SpringBoot project.

Thanks,
Pavan.

Comment: are you trying to connect using http?

Comment: check this out - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41203493/8386848)

Comment: @ahsan I am on Windows. Is this still applicable... Or are you saying that this has to go into a custom Dockerfile?.